# Kafka console producer can connect locally but not remotely

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a single Kafka node at, say, IP address 1.2.3.4.  If I SSH into that node from 2 different terminal windows, and run the console consumer from 1 terminal, and the console producer from another terminal, everything works great:

```
# Run the consumer from terminal 1
kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper zkA:2181 --topic simpletest

# Run the producer from terminal 2
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic simpletest
# Now I can enter messages into terminal 2 and see them show up in terminal 1 (the consumer)
```

If I kill the console producer, but leave the consumer running, and then SSH into a different server (say with IP address of 5.6.7.8), then run the producer, and then try to send a message to Kafka (so that the running consumer picks it up), I get the following warnings:

```
# Run the producer from a terminal on 5.6.7.8
kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 1.2.3.4:9092 --topic simpletest

# Now enter a simple string message to try and send to consumer running on Kafka
hello
[2017-01-25 22:27:21,439] WARN Bootstrap broker 1.2.3.4:9092 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-25 22:27:21,439] WARN Bootstrap broker 1.2.3.4:9092 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-01-25 22:27:21,439] WARN Bootstrap broker 1.2.3.4:9092 disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
...
```

These warnings keep being generated until I kill the producer. Most importantly, the message never arrives and the consumer (again, running on the Kafka node, terminal 1) never spits the "hello" message to the console/STDOUT.

I have confirmed that the server at 5.6.7.8 has network access to 1.2.3.4:9092:

```
telnet 1.2.3.4 9092
Trying 1.2.3.4...
Connected to 1.2.3.4.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

In summary, everything works fine when:

- I can run the console consumer locally on the Kafka node
- I can run the console producer locally on the Kafka node

But I get producer warnings and the messages never arrive when:

- I have the console consumer running locally on Kafka,
- then try to run + send messages from a remote console producer.

I have confirmed that the remote producer has network access to the Kafka node at port 9092.

**Any ideas as to what's going wrong and/or how I could troubleshoot?**

Comment: Check if this helps  [Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521691/kafka-authentication-producer-unable-to-connect-producer)

Comment: Thanks @Gondola_Ride but there's no SASL configured on the broker and besides, the same arguments are passed to the producer in both cases, so args/configs against the same Kafka node and consumer are the same in both cases. I don't think this is a Kafka config issue, and am thinking more along the lines of networking.

Comment: Can you please check `iptables` service or if you happen to use AWS EC2 `security group` settings ?

Comment: Thanks again, but if there was a firewall in place, or if AWS SGs were preventing access, how would the `telnet` command be working?!? But for the record, yes I've confirmed no firewalls and that SGs are configured correctly.

Comment: I have a similar problem with kafka running on VM. Have you found a solution especially for version 0.11.0.0?

Comment: Same situation here, no solution yet :( Were you able to solve it? @sceiler

Comment: Same situation any solution @smeeb ?

Comment: Same situation here...

Answer (score 0):

You should check this out
[Kafka Listener Explanation](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/).

tl:dr from the blog

> You need to set advertised.listeners (or KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS if you’re using Docker images) to the external address (host/IP) so that clients can correctly connect to it. Otherwise they’ll try to connect to the internal host address–and if that’s not reachable then problems ensue.